# Change constraints at runtime

Tags: swift, uiview, constraints

I'm currently making a messaging app in Swift using UIKit. I therefore obviously need to be able to show and hide the keyboard. Actually showing and hiding it is not a problem in itself.

What is a challenge however, is to move only certain views a certain amount when the keyboard is shown/hidden. I have a method to grab the keyboard's height, so getting the right numbers is not a challenge here.

What I'm struggling with is moving the view itself. I have a `UIView` at the bottom of the screen holding a text field and button, and when the keyboard appears, I want this to move up. The issue is that the view has constraints set, and when I try to remove or redefine these, I just get A LOT of errors in the console.

I've tried `bottomView.removeConstraints(bottomView.constraints)` and then redefining all of them, I've tried `bottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(view.bottomAnchor).isActive = false` and then activating another one, but I suspect I lack an understanding of how these programmatic constraints work. I've seen several other Stack Overflow answers mentioning '`bottomView.constant`' or '`bottomView.bottomAnchor.constant`', but it seems like neither the view nor its constraints/anchors have such a property.

Question: How can I move a `UIView` by a fixed distance when the iOS keyboard appears, even though the `UIView` has constraints set already?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IQKeyboardManager. It's very simple.
https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Or you can follow this code below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name:  UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil )
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow( notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            var newHeight: CGFloat
            let duration:TimeInterval = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
            let animationCurveRawNSN = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
            let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
            let animationCurve:UIView.AnimationOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                newHeight = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
            } else {
                newHeight = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height
            }
            let keyboardHeight = newHeight  + 16
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                           delay: TimeInterval(0),
                           options: animationCurve,
                           animations: {
                            self.textFieldBottomConstraint.constant = -keyboardHeight
                            self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
                           completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```